# how is the value coming after type promotion?

Tags: java, type-promotion

In a type promotion example I am getting the output as 515.

I know that the value of `char` c (which is 'a') after it gets promoted to an `int`; but on what system is the value of char decided while promoting it to `int`?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char c = 'a';
        int i = 50000;
        int result = i / c;
        System.out.println("i / c is " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess, what you want to know is that [Java uses Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1). The value for `'a'` can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode).

Comment: here the value is getting promoted to higher one BYTE>CHAR>INT>lONG >FLOAT>DOUBLE (which has to be the approach always) then why in case of function overloading its vice versa ? 
Eg:- 'class OverloadDemo{
void test(int a) { 
System.out.println("a: " + a); 
}  

public static void main(String args[]) { 
OverloadDemo ob = new OverloadDemo(); 
 
ob.test(10l); 
}
'
here the int value should also get promoted to long isn't it although the vice versa works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c` is converted to its ASCII value of `97`.

So, `50000 / 97` ~= `515` because of integer divisions (no floating decimals obtained in the result).

Comment: @Joiner-On Stack Overflow,formatting is not the big deal,actually one's point OR answer must be correct! Also,I don't find any reasons for poor formatting in this answer as I tried to maintain lesser and cleaner! I hope this reason must not be put to downvote answers!